# css - using padding

Tags: css, padding

I want to make some design tweaks. Here is the code for html:

```
<div class="addbox">
<h4><span>Pick your best work from <b class="highlight-text">Flickr</b> to display in your portfolio</span></h4>
<div class="addmenu-item"><span class="addmenu-image"><img class="addmenuimage" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7122/7424355198_72620895bd_m.jpg"></span><span class="addmenu-info">Orchid Profiles</span></div>
<div class="addmenu-item"><span class="addmenu-image"><img class="addmenuimage" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7122/7424355198_72620895bd_m.jpg"></span><span class="addmenu-info">Orchid Profiles</span></div>
</div>​
```

[image]

I'm using `padding-left` for `.addmenu-item` but it is not perfect as you can see in the image. The problem is with the `background` color, I tried some other methods, but no use.

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dkh4q/34/

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Sorry, the problem is that the image item is not spaced perfectly. I forgot to try `margin-left`.

Comment: Why is there only padding left is given.

Comment: what r u looking to get exactly?

Comment: I see no question marks in your question. What are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `padding-left: 20px;` set `margin-left: 20px;` property.

You should know difference between them.

[image]

When you want to separate elements, just use `margin` property not `padding`.

> Padding is the space inside the border, between the border and the
>   actual view's content.
>
> Margins are the spaces outside the border, between the border and the
>   other elements next to this view.

More information about [difference between padding and margins](http://webdesign.about.com/od/faqsandhelp/f/bl_faq5_7a.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I opened your jsfiddle, but I don't understand what is exactly your problem. Try using margin-left.

EDIT: hawaii.five-0 beat me in this.